# Prerender React-snap app faild in postbulid when deploying on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering, react-snap

My build is failing on AWS amplify. I am not able to find the root of the cause.
I have added post build script for react-snap. Once amplify finishes the npm run build successfully, react-snap is initiated. Once it is done successfully, the build fails. I have tried the same locally and it is working.

[react-snap fail on aws amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajdyz.png)

I have updated amplify.yml file also on aws, here's my /amplify.yml:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - curl -k https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash
        - npm i
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build --force
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```